# .toggle() all divs that have a height over 99px

Tags: jquery

I am making an accordion type effect, using toggle to expand and contract the height of the div.

When the user toggles a div it expands in height and I want the previous one to toggle back as well.
So, I need to  select all the siblings but I only want to target the div that has been expanded, to shrink its height down again.

I would like to select the expanded div using a function using the condition if height is over 99 px, I thought it the best way to select only expanded divs.

Where am I going wrong?

My code.

```
$(function() {
     jQuery.fn.selectOpen = (function(){
         //(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                if ( $(this).height() > 99) {
                $(this).trigger(".toggle");
                }
                });
            }); 


$("#arrow_01").toggle(function(){
$("#arrow_01").attr('src','images/arrow_down.png');
    $("#expanding_box_01").animate({height: '100px',  }).siblings().selectOpen();
 }, function(){     
   $('#arrow_01').attr('src','images/arrow_right.png');
   $("#expanding_box_01").animate( {height: '27px' });
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.each()` to traverse all siblings, also you mistakenly use `.toggle` as event name while it should be just `toggle`, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.selectOpen = function(){
         //(this).css('background-color', 'red');
         this.each(function() {
             if ( $(this).height() > 99) {
                 $(this).trigger("toggle");
             }
         });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating it. You could use CSS and some classes to determine if an item is open:

```
// bind a click event to an anchor tag
$("#accordian li > a").click(function(){        
    var $box = $(this).parent();
    // if the item has the closed class, proceed, otherwise
    // it is already open
    if ($box.is(":not(.open)")) {
        // animate the currently open sibling closed
        // remove the open class
        $box.siblings(".open").animate( {height: '27px' }).removeClass("open");
        // animate the clicked item and add open class
        $box.animate({height: '100px' }).addClass("open");
    }            
}); ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/qSE69/